# How Can I require a Minimum Quantity on an e-commerce Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, e-commerce

How Can I require a Minimum Quantity on an e-commerce Form?

I am using a Mal's Cart form, and have a Price Break, but I want to Require my customers to have a minimum of 15 units.

I tried adding this to the existing javascript validate function from Serif WebPlus X6), It does not work.:

```
if('qty1'>=15) {return true;} else{ alert("Please enter Minimum Order of 15.") return false;}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus X6 (14.0.0.020)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=960">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_ys-12x18-1c2s( form )
    {
      //Custom Validation Steps

      if( ltrim(rtrim(form.elements['qty1'].value,' '),' ')=="" ) { alert("Please enter some text"); form.elements['qty1'].focus(); return false; }
      if( isNaN( parseInt( form.elements['qty1'].value ) ) ) { alert("Please enter a number"); form.elements['qty1'].focus(); return false; }
      if('qty1'>=15) {return true;} else{ alert("Please enter Minimum Order of 15.") return false;}

      //Custom Validation for element
      return true;
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{margin:0;padding:0;}
    .Button1,.Button1:link,.Button1:visited{background-image:url('wpimages/wp5325eb44_06.png');background-position:0px 0px;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;background-color:transparent;border:none 0px;padding:0;}
    .Button1:focus{outline-style:none;}
    .Button1:hover{background-position:0px -45px;}
    .Button1 span,.Button1:link span,.Button1:visited span{color:#ffffff;font-family:"Futura LtCn BT",sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;text-transform:none;font-style:normal;left:9px;top:5px;width:127px;height:35px;font-size:27px;display:block;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;}
    .Button1:hover span{color:#000000;left:18px;width:110px;}
    .Button1:active span{color:#000000;left:18px;width:110px;}
  </style>
</head>

<body text="#000000" style="background:#ffffff; height:1000px;">
<div style="background-color:transparent;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;width:960px;height:1000px;">
  <form id="ys-12x18-1c2s" onsubmit="return validate_ys-12x18-1c2s(this)" action="http://12.aitsafe.com/cf/addmulti.cfm" method="post" target="_self" style="margin:0;position:absolute;left:16px;top:13px;width:240px;height:125px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="product1[]" value="Yard Signs 12&quot;x18&quot; -1 Color-2 Side">
    <input type="hidden" name="scode1" value="YdSgn-12x18-1c-2s">
    <input type="hidden" name="price1" value="104.25">
    <input type="hidden" name="discountpr1" value="24,6.99:25,4.99:50,3.09:50,2.29:100,2.09:250,1.99:500,1.89:9001,1.79">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.MYDOMAIN.com/index.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="lg" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="MYNUMBER">
    <img src="wpimages/wpe73c68aa_06.png" border="0" width="60" height="20" title="" alt="QUANTITY&#10;" style="position:absolute;left:72px;top:25px;">
    <input type="text" name="qty1" value="15" style="position:absolute; left:147px; top:25px; width:50px;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:62px;top:58px;width:145px;height:45px;"><button type="submit" id="btn_311" class="Button1" style="width:145px;height:45px;"><span>ADD&nbsp;TO&nbsp;CART</span></button></div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jsValidation.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a string to the number 15, not the value in the field labeled 'qty1'. Take a look at the conditional checks in the lines above yours. You likely need something like this:

```
if( parseInt( form.elements['qty1'].value ) >=15) {return true;} 
else{ alert("Please enter Minimum Order of 15."); return false;}
```

Comment: Still does not seem to work: //Custom Validation Steps
    
 `code`   if( ltrim(rtrim(form.elements['qty1'].value,' '),' ')=="" ) { alert("Please enter some text"); form.elements['qty1'].focus(); return false; }
    if( isNaN( parseInt( form.elements['qty1'].value ) ) ) { alert("Please enter a number"); form.elements['qty1'].focus(); return false; }
    if( parseInt( form.elements['qty1'].value ) >=15) {return true;} else{ alert("Please enter Minimum Order of 15.") return false;} `code`

Comment: @Mahogan - You were missing a semi-colon at the end of the alert. I've edited the answer to show the change.

Comment: Carth - - tried that, no luck.  I uploaded the actual form here: http://www.mahogan.com/mals-form/

Comment: @Mahogan You have a script error on your page. validate_ys-12x18-1c2s is an invalid function name. Hyphens are not allowed in function names.

Comment: @Mahogan You could also just do this to make the comparison once you fix the function name: $("input[name*='qty1']").value >= 15

Comment: Carth -- Thats it!  I did not realize that hyphens in my form name would mess me up!  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Mahogan - Happy to help! If this answered your questions please be sure to mark it as the answer :)